# AWS Cloudformation: Fn::GetAtt into Fn::ImportValue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a stack to create an VPC.

This stack exports an output for VPC ID with name `VPCID`. Lools like this.

```yaml
Outputs:

  Output0:
    Description: The ID of the VPC 
    Value: !Ref VPC0
    Export:
      Name: VPCID
```

I can import the output into my child stacks.

```yaml
  sghttps:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: 'HTTPS'
      GroupName: https
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - FromPort: 443 
          ToPort: 443 
          IpProtocol: tcp 
          CidrIp: '0.0.0.0/0'
          Description: 'HTTPS from EVERYWHERE'
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - FromPort: 0
          ToPort: 0
          IpProtocol: '-1'
          CidrIp: '0.0.0.0/0'
      VpcId: !ImportValue VPCID
      Tags:
        - Key: CF
          Value: true
```

Now, I need access to the attribute `CidrBlock` of this VPC in my child stacks.

Somethigs like this.

```yaml
  sgmongodb:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: 'MONGODB'
      GroupName: mongodb
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - FromPort: 27017
          ToPort: 27017
          IpProtocol: tcp 
          CidrIp: !ImportValue VPCID.CidrBlock
          Description: 'MongoDB from our VPC TCP'
```

or like this.

```yaml
  sgmongodb:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: 'MONGODB'
      GroupName: mongodb
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - FromPort: 27017
          ToPort: 27017
          IpProtocol: tcp 
          CidrIp: !ImportValue 'Fn::GetAtt':
            - VPCID
            - CidrBlock
          Description: 'MongoDB from our VPC TCP'
```

I'm aware that is posible export the value of CidrBlock.

```yaml
Outputs:

  Output0:
    Description: The ID of the VPC 
    Value: !Ref VPC0
    Export:
      Name: VPCID


  Output1:
    Description: CidrBlock
    Value: !GetAtt VPC0.CidrBlock                                                                                        
    Export:
      Name: VPCIDCidrBlock
```

But, Is posible pass only the main VPS (`VPCID` in my case) resource and get the attribute `CidrBlock` in the child stack?

I do not find the rigth syntax. Any idea?

Comment: You'll have to create an explicit export for each thing you need to import elsewhere. You can do the `!GetAtt` in the output section. Exports are just string values, not a reference to the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, Is posible pass only the main VPS (VPCID in my case) resource and get the attribute CidrBlock in the child stack?

No its not, without a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in your child module. Such a resource would be in the form of a **lambda function** which would take the VPCID as an input paramter, used AWS SDK to query the VPC for its CIDR range, and return it to your child stack for further use.

If you don't want to create a custom resource, you have to **export your CIDR** range as well, and any other info that you require.